# Finite field question involving the trace and a permutation.

Tags: finite-fields, trace

Let $q$ be a power of a prime $p$, and $m,l$ positive integers with gcd$(l,q^m-1)=1$. Denote $Tr$ to be the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace) of $GF(q^m)$ over $GF(q)$.

Suppose that there exists a nonzero $\gamma \in GF(q^m)$ such that 
$$ Tr(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow Tr(\gamma x^l)=0, \;\text{ for all } x\in GF(q^m).  \;\;\;\;\;\;\text{(1)}$$

I'm pretty sure that Equation $(1)$ implies that $\gamma \in GF(q)$ and $l$ is a power of $p$ (the converse is clearly true).

Am I right? If so, how can I prove it?

---

So far I have unsuccesfully tried to prove it, using the following in one way or the other:

- $\gamma x^l$ is a permutation of $GF(q^m)$
- The roots of $Tr$ are *exactly* the elements $a^{q}-a$ for $a\in GF(q^m)$
- The formal derivative of $Tr(\gamma x^l)$ is $l x^{l-1}$. Showing that it is zero implies that $p|l$.
- Try to show that $Tr(\gamma x^l)=\gamma(Tr(x))^l$

I feel that the last point is the key; if this is shown, then one can compare coefficients and take it from there. I also feel that the proof should be very simple, but I'm stuck.

---

Another thing I just read about, from Lidl & Niederreiter's book "Finite Fields", and looks highly relevant:

**Theorem.** *A polynomial $f\in GF(q)$ is a permutation polynomial of all finite extensions of $GF(q)$ iff it is of the form $f(x)=ax^{p^h}+b$, where $a\neq 0$, $p$ is the characteristic of $GF(q)$, and $h$ is a nonnegative integer.*

Comment: Ok. This is a cool question. Unfortunately it's late here, and I'm a bit drunk. I don't see it right away, but there might be a trick... Anyway, I would be at least a bit surprised if this is not true.

Comment: I know a couple of people who were claiming that they could do math better after a couple of beers :) Anyway, I think I have an idea, but I have to double think before posting anything, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: If $q=2$ then the claim follows because the assumption implies that $Tr(x)=Tr(\gamma x^\ell)$ for *all* $x\in GF(2^m)$. The rest is along the lines of [this argument](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1161378/11619). For the difference of the two traces of monomials to vanish universally it is necessary that their exponents belong to the same cyclotomic coset et cetera.

Comment: Many thanks Jyrki, I'll need to study this a bit. I'll update later.

Answer (score 0):

I Think is kinda late, but i was looking for something like that i would like to share it:
I think the easy way is to see that $|Ker(Tr)|=q^{m-1}$ (if you see it as a linear transformation $Ker : GF(q^{m})\rightarrow GF(q)$), and then count all the elements $\gamma x^{l}$

Or you could also use that $Tr(x)=0 \leftrightarrow x=y^{q}-y $ for some $y\in GF(q^{m})$

Plus i dont think this is relevant, but your question can traslate to Coding Theory, and you´ll be asking what are all the linear transformations of a code (In this case a Trace code) that preserve the Hamming weight, which would be all the multiplication for an element of the base field and a permutation of the coordinates, which would traslate to the "trasformations" $\gamma x^{l}$ in this context.